# Prove If $a^3>a$ then $a^5>a$

Tags: proof-verification

Prove If $a^3>a$ then $a^5>a$

Here was my go at it:
Assume $a^3>a$. Then
$$a^3>a\Rightarrow a^3-a>0\Rightarrow a(a+1)(a-1)>0$$ 
Solving this inequality gives the truth set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:-1<x<0\lor x>1\}$.
Then solving the inequality $a^5>a$ I get the same truth set, since $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Does this prove that $$a^3>a\Rightarrow a^5>a$$ Does this also mean $$a^5>a\Rightarrow a^3>a$$ 
I'm just learning how to write proofs and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:-1<x<0,x>1\}$ is **empty**: that is probably not what you meant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Edited. Thanks!

Comment: There you go :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $a<a^3$. We must have $a\neq0$ and then $a^2>0$. It follows that we can multiply the inequality by $a^2$ without breaking it, and we get $a^3<a^5$.

Comment: It took me so long to figure out $a<a^3$ is the same as $a^3>a$. For some reason I was reading it as $a^3<a$. Time for more coffee I guess :). So I think I understand. Just so I'm not misunderstanding, that also shows that $a^3>a\Rightarrow a^5>a$ right? Edit. Just read Newb's answer so now this makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dserver I didn't realize this was the same as my answer either. I also found it unintuitive that the inequality should proceed <lesser> < <greater> --- I'm used to them being written <greater> > <lesser>

Answer (score 3):

All the other approaches are way too complicated. You can prove this straight from the field axioms, and the rules of order. You know $a^3 > a$. I assume we know $a \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now take $a^2$. We know $a^2 > 0$. So $a^2$ is definitely positive. (Just in case: if you don't know this, I'll write the proof in a comment.)

By the rules of order: multiplication by positive elements, we know that $a^3 \cdot a^2 > a \cdot a^2$. That is, $a^5 > a^3$. So $a^5 > a^3 > a$. By transitivity, $a^5 > a$.

Comment: Proof that $\forall a \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}, a^2 > 0$:

By trichotomy, there are only two possibilities: $a > 0$ or $a < 0$. If $a >0$, then $a \cdot a > a \cdot 0$, which we know from the rules of order: multiplication by positive elements. If $a < 0$, then $-a > 0$, and $-a \ cdot -a > -a \cdot 0 \Longrightarrow (-1)(-1)a^2 > 0 \Longrightarrow a^2 > 0$.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to look at it is: $a^2 + 1 > 0$. Why?

$a^5 - a = a(a^2-1)(a^2+1) = (a^2+1)(a^3-a)$ and $a^2+1\geq1>0$ and $a^3-a>0$ by hypothesis. Hence, $a^5-a>0$.

As for truth sets, they are overkill and definitely not the best way to proceed.

Comment: I don't understand what that inequality does here...

Comment: Well... $a^5-a = a(a^4-1) = (a^2+1)\cdot (a^3-a)$, where $a^2+1>0$ and $a^3-a>0$. So, $a^5-a>0$.

Comment: Why should $a^2-1$ be greater than $0$? Try for instance $a=-\frac12$.

Comment: @TonyK: thank you for pointing that out, I corrected it.

Comment: It would be beest if instead of a «the proof follows» you wrote down a complete argument, really. The connection from $a^2+1$ to the wanted inequality is quite non-obvious!

Comment: Hence the downvote? However, I stand by not giving a complete argument here; it was meant to guide the OP not hold their hands.

Comment: Please, do not assume that it was me who downvoted —you'd be wrong. I do not think your answer is a good one, though, as it stands.

Comment: I don't disagree. Your criticism was justified.

Comment: I can understand why truth sets would be overkill for someone who can see solutions to easy inequalities at a glance, but can you elaborate on why they aren't a good way to proceed? Is there a case when using them will lead me in the wrong direction? At this point I'm only working on proofs of $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$